# how to get icon of application

Tags: android, icons

i need to get the icon of application instead of their names.
how can I achieve this. I already have the code to get their names

```
    final List<ResolveInfo> activities = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities (i, 0);

    List<String> appNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (ResolveInfo info : activities) {
        appNames.add(info.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString());
    }

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Title");
    builder.setItems(appNames.toArray(new CharSequence[appNames.size()]), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            i.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
```

Comment: Do you know the package names of the apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use `loadIcon()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ResolveInfo.html#loadIcon%28android.content.pm.PackageManager%29) in addition to `loadLabel()`.

For example, this activity (from [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Introspection/Launchalot)) displays a list of `LAUNCHER` apps, using icons and labels:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2008-2012 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    https://commonsware.com/Android
*/

package com.commonsware.android.launchalot;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Launchalot extends ListActivity {
  AppAdapter adapter=null;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
    Intent main=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);

    main.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    List<ResolveInfo> launchables=pm.queryIntentActivities(main, 0);

    Collections.sort(launchables,
                     new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm)); 

    adapter=new AppAdapter(pm, launchables);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v,
                                 int position, long id) {
    ResolveInfo launchable=adapter.getItem(position);
    ActivityInfo activity=launchable.activityInfo;
    ComponentName name=new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName,
                                         activity.name);
    Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
    i.setComponent(name);

    startActivity(i);    
  }

  class AppAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ResolveInfo> {
    private PackageManager pm=null;

    AppAdapter(PackageManager pm, List<ResolveInfo> apps) {
      super(Launchalot.this, R.layout.row, apps);
      this.pm=pm;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                          ViewGroup parent) {
      if (convertView==null) {
        convertView=newView(parent);
      }

      bindView(position, convertView);

      return(convertView);
    }

    private View newView(ViewGroup parent) {
      return(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false));
    }

    private void bindView(int position, View row) {
      TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.label);

      label.setText(getItem(position).loadLabel(pm));

      ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);

      icon.setImageDrawable(getItem(position).loadIcon(pm));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but do i need another arraylist or i can just change the type of this arraylist

Comment: @ddnice: You would need to [create a custom adapter and use `setAdapter()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener)). `setItems()` knows nothing about icons.

Comment: Ok ill give a try and tell you